# How to get text from a KivyMD text field?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to get text from a text field, but I can't seem to get it right. I want to get the text from the MDTextField in the LoginScreen. This is my .kv file:

```
ScreenManager:
    LoginScreen:
    VaultScreen:
<LoginScreen>:
    id: login
    name: 'login'
    MDTextField:
        id: master_password
        hint_text: "Master Password"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
        font_size: 18
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        password: True
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "Unlock"
        font_size: 12
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.4}
        on_release: app.verify()
<VaultScreen>:
    name: 'vault'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Vault'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'login'
```

And this is my .py file:

```
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    
    class ScMn(ScreenManager):
        pass
    
    class LoginScreen(Screen):
        pass
    
    class VaultScreen(Screen):
        pass
    
    class App(MDApp):
        def build(self):
            screen = Builder.load_file('passr.kv')
            return screen
        
        def verify(self):
            # this is where I want to get the text
            master = self.root.ids.login.master_password.text
            pass
        
    App().run()
```

When I try getting the contents of self.root.ids I get an empty dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
self.root.ids.login.master_password.text
```

is trying to access the `ids` of `self.root`, but `self.root` is the `ScreenManager`, and it has no `ids`. The `ids` defined in `kv` are stored in the `ids` dictionary of the widget that is the the root of the rule that contains the `id` definition. Since you define some `ids` in the `<LoginScreen>` rule, the `ids` will be in the `LoginScreen` object. So you must get a reference to the `LoginScreen`, and you can do that by using the `get_screen()` method, like this:

```
self.root.get_screen('login').ids.master_password.text
```